# Android : Can't select multiple files

Tags: android, android-file

I need to attach some files in my application. I have used [this](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-Multiple-file-Selector-Dialog/blob/master/README.md) library to select multiple files and I want to keep it in a array.

This is the code I have followed from there.

```
private static final String FILES_TO_UPLOAD = null;
Intent intent = new Intent(_context, FileSelectionActivity.class);
((Activity) _context).startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<File> Files = (ArrayList<File>) data.getSerializableExtra(FILES_TO_UPLOAD); //file array list
        String [] files_paths = null; //string array
        int i = 0;

        for(File file : Files){
            //String fileName = file.getName();
            String uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
            files_paths[i] = uri.toString(); //storing the selected file's paths to string array files_paths
            i++;
        }
    }else{
    }

}
```

I'am getting `NullPointerException` in the Files.

Could anyone point me where I did mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `onActivityResult` if you dont got fixed please comment below

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<File> Files = (ArrayList<File>) data
                        .getSerializableExtra(FILES_TO_UPLOAD); // file array list
                String[] files_paths = new String[] {}; // string array
                int i = 0;
                if (Files != null) {

                    for (File file : Files) {
                        // String fileName = file.getName();
                        String uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        files_paths[i] = uri.toString(); // storing the selected
                                                            // file's paths to
                                                            // string array
                                                            // files_paths
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
            }


    }
```

Comment: I'am getting null value in  ArrayList<File> Files = (ArrayList<File>) data                      .getSerializableExtra(FILES_TO_UPLOAD); this line.

Comment: try this library i used in several project for your req https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Comment: I think it is only applicable for images and not for other file types